# how to create column dynamically in grails 2.4.4 using GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I want to create a table in my database based on file upload. Means once upload the csv file then only that should create tables in my database and for each csv file a new table should be created dynamically.

now am trying to upload file from controller. from controller i should pass fields values to domain class  and tables name same as the csv file name how can i solve this?

Comment: This is simply not possible. You cannot define Domain object that have dynamic properties at runtime.

What are you trying to solve? What is your use case?

Comment: i need to store csv file in db along with the data and each csv file should store in separate table and and table name should be same as  csv file name.

Comment: While reading the csv file, form a create table query and execute it. This create table query would be dynamic and you need to be sure that you are using proper type and constraints. Alternative could be to use Mongo.

Answer (score 0):

A relational database really isn't a good fit for a dynmaic persistence model, something like MongoDB would be better. The best you can do with a GORM domain model is something like

```
class CsvFile {
    String fileName
    static hasMany = [rows: Row]
}

class Row {
    static belongsTo = [csvFile: CsvFile]
    Map<String, Object> fields
}
```

I realise this doesn't exactly match your requirement insofar as each CSV file being stored in a separate table, but that's just not really practical with a GORM domain model being stored in a relational database.